# MongoDB sort and limit performance issue

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

I'm facing with a strange issue. The explain of the query shows usage of index with a fast execution time in all stages but the last stage of LIMIT breaks it all. I have execution time of 60s and more!

The DB is used for marketing tool and we collect data on the campaign activity. We have 100k+ records in DB **per each hour** and I want to select all the 100k in batches of 5k (I tried to reduce it to 1k also) in order to make statistics aggregation.

Just for tests, I will add an example of the query explanation.

- If I reduce the `created_at` date range to 10 minutes and I set the `limit` to 1000, it works fast.
- If I set the `created_at` date range to 30 minutes and I set the `limit` to 1000, it stock again.
- I have 8 CPU and 64 memory
- Storage is with 6000 IOPS
- The table include 900 million records in total

I have the following indexes:

- created_at: 1
- _id: 1
- {created_at: 1, _id: 1} - not used in query

Slow query for 30 minutes

```
> db.logs.explain('allPlansExecution').aggregate([{"$match":{"created_at":{"$gte":ISODate('2021-06-02T20:00:00.000+00:00'),"$lte":ISODate('2021-06-02T20:30:00.000+00:00')}}},{"$sort":{"_id":1}},{"$limit":1000}], { allowDiskUse: true });
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "webpush.campaign_action_logs",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "created_at" : {
                        "$lte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:30:00Z")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "created_at" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:00:00Z")
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "optimizedPipeline" : true,
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "memLimit" : 104857600,
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "type" : "simple",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "created_at" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "created_at_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "created_at" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "created_at" : [
                            "[new Date(1622664000000), new Date(1622665800000)]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "created_at" : {
                                    "$lte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:30:00Z")
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "created_at" : {
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:00:00Z")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "_id_",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "_id" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : true,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "_id" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 100,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 183411,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 257959,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 257959,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "nReturned" : 100,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 625,
            "works" : 258061,
            "advanced" : 100,
            "needTime" : 257960,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 9571,
            "restoreState" : 9571,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "memLimit" : 104857600,
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "type" : "simple",
            "totalDataSizeSorted" : 187871472,
            "usedDisk" : false,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "nReturned" : 257959,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 533,
                "works" : 257960,
                "advanced" : 257959,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 9571,
                "restoreState" : 9571,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "docsExamined" : 257959,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 257959,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 265,
                    "works" : 257960,
                    "advanced" : 257959,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 9571,
                    "restoreState" : 9571,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "created_at" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "created_at_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "created_at" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "created_at" : [
                            "[new Date(1622664000000), new Date(1622665800000)]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 257959,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [
            {
                "nReturned" : 100,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 625,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 257959,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 257959,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT",
                    "nReturned" : 100,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 625,
                    "works" : 258060,
                    "advanced" : 100,
                    "needTime" : 257960,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 9571,
                    "restoreState" : 9571,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "sortPattern" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                    },
                    "memLimit" : 104857600,
                    "limitAmount" : 100,
                    "type" : "simple",
                    "totalDataSizeSorted" : 187871472,
                    "usedDisk" : false,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "nReturned" : 257959,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 533,
                        "works" : 257960,
                        "advanced" : 257959,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 9571,
                        "restoreState" : 9571,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "docsExamined" : 257959,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 257959,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 265,
                            "works" : 257960,
                            "advanced" : 257959,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 9571,
                            "restoreState" : 9571,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "created_at" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "created_at_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "created_at" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "created_at" : [
                                    "[new Date(1622664000000), new Date(1622665800000)]"
                                ]
                            },
                            "keysExamined" : 257959,
                            "seeks" : 1,
                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 70,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 178092,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 258060,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 258060,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "LIMIT",
                    "nReturned" : 70,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 178092,
                    "works" : 258060,
                    "advanced" : 70,
                    "needTime" : 257990,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 9571,
                    "restoreState" : 9571,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "limitAmount" : 100,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "created_at" : {
                                        "$lte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:30:00Z")
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "created_at" : {
                                        "$gte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:00:00Z")
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 70,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 178057,
                        "works" : 258060,
                        "advanced" : 70,
                        "needTime" : 257990,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 9571,
                        "restoreState" : 9571,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "docsExamined" : 258060,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 258060,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 645,
                            "works" : 258060,
                            "advanced" : 258060,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 9571,
                            "restoreState" : 9571,
                            "isEOF" : 0,
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "_id" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "_id_",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "_id" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : true,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            },
                            "keysExamined" : 258060,
                            "seeks" : 1,
                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "ip-10-0-3-171",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.4.6",
        "gitVersion" : "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Faster query for 10 minutes:**

```
> db.logs.explain('allPlansExecution').aggregate([{"$match":{"created_at":{"$gte":ISODate('2021-06-02T20:00:00.000+00:00'),"$lte":ISODate('2021-06-02T20:10:00.000+00:00')}}},{"$sort":{"_id":1}},{"$limit":1000}], { allowDiskUse: true });
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "webpush.campaign_action_logs",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "created_at" : {
                        "$lte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:10:00Z")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "created_at" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:00:00Z")
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "optimizedPipeline" : true,
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "memLimit" : 104857600,
            "limitAmount" : 1000,
            "type" : "simple",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "created_at" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "created_at_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "created_at" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "created_at" : [
                            "[new Date(1622664000000), new Date(1622664600000)]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 1000,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "created_at" : {
                                    "$lte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:10:00Z")
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "created_at" : {
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:00:00Z")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "_id_",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "_id" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : true,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "_id" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1000,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 1502,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 58027,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 58027,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "nReturned" : 1000,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 122,
            "works" : 59029,
            "advanced" : 1000,
            "needTime" : 58028,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 122,
            "restoreState" : 122,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "memLimit" : 104857600,
            "limitAmount" : 1000,
            "type" : "simple",
            "totalDataSizeSorted" : 42213931,
            "usedDisk" : false,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "nReturned" : 58027,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 96,
                "works" : 58028,
                "advanced" : 58027,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 122,
                "restoreState" : 122,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "docsExamined" : 58027,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 58027,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 40,
                    "works" : 58028,
                    "advanced" : 58027,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 122,
                    "restoreState" : 122,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "created_at" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "created_at_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "created_at" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "created_at" : [
                            "[new Date(1622664000000), new Date(1622664600000)]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 58027,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [
            {
                "nReturned" : 101,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 122,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 58027,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 58027,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT",
                    "nReturned" : 101,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 122,
                    "works" : 58129,
                    "advanced" : 101,
                    "needTime" : 58028,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 121,
                    "restoreState" : 121,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "sortPattern" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                    },
                    "memLimit" : 104857600,
                    "limitAmount" : 1000,
                    "type" : "simple",
                    "totalDataSizeSorted" : 42213931,
                    "usedDisk" : false,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "nReturned" : 58027,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 96,
                        "works" : 58028,
                        "advanced" : 58027,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 121,
                        "restoreState" : 121,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "docsExamined" : 58027,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 58027,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 40,
                            "works" : 58028,
                            "advanced" : 58027,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 121,
                            "restoreState" : 121,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "created_at" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "created_at_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "created_at" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "created_at" : [
                                    "[new Date(1622664000000), new Date(1622664600000)]"
                                ]
                            },
                            "keysExamined" : 58027,
                            "seeks" : 1,
                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 3,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 935,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 58129,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 58129,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "LIMIT",
                    "nReturned" : 3,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 935,
                    "works" : 58129,
                    "advanced" : 3,
                    "needTime" : 58126,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 122,
                    "restoreState" : 122,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "limitAmount" : 1000,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "created_at" : {
                                        "$lte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:10:00Z")
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "created_at" : {
                                        "$gte" : ISODate("2021-06-02T20:00:00Z")
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 3,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 935,
                        "works" : 58129,
                        "advanced" : 3,
                        "needTime" : 58126,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 122,
                        "restoreState" : 122,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "docsExamined" : 58129,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 58129,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 17,
                            "works" : 58129,
                            "advanced" : 58129,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 122,
                            "restoreState" : 122,
                            "isEOF" : 0,
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "_id" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "_id_",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "_id" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : true,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "_id" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            },
                            "keysExamined" : 58129,
                            "seeks" : 1,
                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "ip-10-0-3-171",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.4.6",
        "gitVersion" : "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Questions:

- If the issue is the amount of doc scanned and we used index, how can I solve it? I do not think that looping over 5000k results in a sort order in a 300k docs should cuz an issue but maybe I'm wrong.
- Why the LIMIT stage (with another stage of FETCH) causing the issue?

Thank you very much for all experts in advance!

Comment: How does your query perform without the _sort_ stage (I would try this to understand the issue).

Comment: @prasad_ nice question, without the sorting we are talking about few ms query. Super fast. The issue is that I must sort the results because I need to jump between each 5000 items and to use "skip" and "limit" is not a good practice when you need to skip 100k items. https://sammaye.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/mongodb-paging-using-ranged-queries-avoiding-skip/

Comment: Your query has the disadvantage of having a range filter in the $match stage. This doesn't allow the $sort to use an index. It is the sort stage that is doing an in-memory sort - it is not able to use an index. How many documents are returned _after_ the $match stage? (Note: I did not read the linked article).

Comment: Hey, the article is just to explain why I avoid skip/limit. @prasad_the docs after match you can see in the first "explain" I added in the message, in the first stage of match we have "docsExamined" : 257959 and I want to return a limit of 5000 items, then to skip by IDs for the next 5000.

Comment: You can possibly benefit from _adding another filter with equality condition_ in the $match stage (along with the present filter) - that way we can have the sort stage use an index.

Comment: Do you mean to reduce the 257k results with another filter in $match stage and like this the index will be used? or you mean just to reduce the docs and like this the sort will be faster? @prasad_

Comment: You can possibly benefit from the **ESR Rule** in this post: [Performance Best Practices: Indexing](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing). But, this will require you rethink your query, little bit. This can apply one compound index on all the fields of the filter and the sort field.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the sort.  Because you are using skip/limit on a sorted set, it must load the *entire* set from disk, then sort it in memory (possibly spilling to disk) in order to apply the skip/limit.

This means that if you have 100k documents matching the time range, you load all 100k to get the first batch, and then load 100k *again* to get the second batch.

An index in mongodb can support a sort if the index includes the field that is sorted on, and any fields that precede that key in the index creation spec are matched with an equality predicate.

Fields matched with inequality or ranges can be listed after the sort key.

The existing index on `{ _id:1 }` is inefficient because it is non-selective and therefore requires reading the entire collection from diks.

The index on `{ created_at:1 }` requires loading only those document that match the query, but they must then be sorted in memory.

To support this query, create an index on `{ _id:1, created_at:1 }`.  This index should significantly improve the performance because it can both eliminate the in-memory sort, and only require the query executor to load from disk those documents that match the query.  This also has the benefit that the query executor can terminate as soon as the limit is satisfied.

Comment: "create an index on { _id:1, created_at:1 }" didn't want.. it was not used in the query. Same results. I also try to swipe the order.

Comment: Could you show the allPlansExecution output that considered those indexes?